# how to use a different value from that selected in a drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to figure out how (if possible, which I'm sure I can) to use a different value to that selected in a drop down box in HTML. Happy to use jQuery or JavaScript. So for example I have a series of dropdowns as follows:

```
<select id="country" title="Country">
    <option>Argentina ARG</option>
    <option>Australia AUS</option>
    <option>Austria AUT</option>
    <option>Austria AUT</option>
    <option>Belgium BEL</option>
    <option>Brazil BRA</option>
    <option>Canada CAN</option>
</select>
```

Naturally when a user chooses say 'Brazil' the option displays 'Brazil BRA'. However, I would like to instead use the value 'BRA' is it possible to do this? Am I just being dumb and it can be done in plain HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<option value="BRA">Brazil BRA</option>
```

Side note: I believe IE6 needs that `value` or things get funky onsubmit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the value attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp

Comment: +1 for right answer. -1 for linking to W3Fools. You broke even.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="country" title="Country">
    <option value="ARG">Argentina</option>
    <option value="AUS">Australia</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the options value-attribute. This way the text that is shown to the user is Argentina ARG, but the value that is posted with the form is just ARG.

```
<select id="country" title="Country">
    <option value="ARG">Argentina ARG</option>
    <option value="AUS">Australia AUS</option>
             ...
</select>
```